# Ajax Printing Database Records to Multiple Fields

Tags: php, ajax, database

I currently have code which will pull the first element from a database record and print it in an output box.

What is the easiest way to print the rest of the elements of that record to the other relevant output boxes?

My PHP file takes an 'id' specified by the user.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE ID = $id";
$result= mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

    echo $row[1];

 }
}
```

And this is the code in the HTML file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
jQuery("input.myid").keyup(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    ajax_search(); 
 }); 
});

function ajax_search(){
var search_val=jQuery("input.myid").val(); 
jQuery.post("find.php", {id : search_val}, function(data){
 if (data.length>0){ 
 jQuery("input.fname").val(data); 
  } 
 }); 
}
```

The code takes the id ('myid') and prints to a text box named 'fname'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it easier to json_encode the whole thing (record I mean) and use something like [jquery.populate](http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html) which basically takes an object and fills a form with it (all fields it can find which names' match properties from the object).

I hope this makes sense.